# PHP/jQuery Ajax strange outcome, need some advice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a bit of an issue that I cannot get my head around.
I have an let's call it an 'insert page' where The user enters in a Firstname, Lastname and there is a dropdown of a list of 'floors'. Now on each floor there are workstations. So when the user selects a floor I make an Ajax call to bring back the workstations for that floor:

Insert Floor Ajax:

```
 $('#floor').change(function (){
    if ($('#floor option:selected').text() == "Please select a floor"){
        $('#workstation').slideUp();
    } else {
        $('#workstation').slideDown();
    }
    $floor = $('#floor option:selected').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "workstationAjax.php",
        data: {floor: $floor},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function (i, msg) {
                $('#workstation').append("<option id='department' name='department' value=" + msg.floor_id + ">" + msg.description + "</option>")
            });
        }
    });
});
```

WorkstationAjax.php

```
<?php

header ("content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
require_once '../Config/db.php';

if (!isset($_POST['floor']) || $_POST['floor'] == "") {
    return false;
} else {

$floorID = $_POST['floor'];
$query = $conn->query("select * from workstation where floor_id= $floorID");
$query->execute();

$array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo json_encode($array);

}
```

So it returns the correct 'workstations' but when selecting the workstation options from the drop down it keeps appending every selection to the first option in the dropdown and I cannot figure out why...

HTML

```
        <h3><strong>Insert Employee</strong></h3>
    <form id="insertEmployee" action="admin/insert.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Enter Firstname" class="form-control-static"/>
        <p/>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Enter Lastname"  class="form-control-static" />
        <br />

        <select id="floor" name="floor">
            <option value="">Please select a floor</option>
            <?php
            $floorArray = getData("floor");
            foreach ($floorArray as $key=> $row) {
                echo "<option id='floor' name='floor' value=\"{$row['floor_id']}\">{$row['description']}</option>";
            }

            ?>

        </select>
<br>
        <select id="workstation" anme="workstation">

        </select>
 <br />
        <select id="department" name="department">


        </select>
```

EDIT:
I have fixed it. It was a very stupid mistake but not sure how it's fixed... Will have to take a further look. On the Insert floor Ajax I changed:
From:

```
            $.each(data, function (i, msg) {
            $('#workstation').append("<option id='department' name='department' value=" + msg.floor_id + ">" + msg.description + "</option>")
        });
```

To:

```
            $.each(data, function (i, msg) {
            $('#workstation').append("<option id='workstation' name='workstation' value=" + msg.floor_id + ">" + msg.description + "</option>")
        });
```

Comment: it's very possible you're seeing strange behavior because you're giving each `<option>` element the same ID. ID's should be unique, or change that to `class`. And you have `anme` instead of `name` for *workstation*

Comment: In HTML, an `id` must be unique in the document.  It may not be much of an issue, but `name` is also not valid on `option` elements. See documentation for [element.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.name) and [element.id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id)